# malformedXML: During update: outerTab:j_idt185 not found; iframe id="JSFFrameId"

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, facelets

I have a form with a PrimeFaces selectOneMenu which, when the user selects an option, I want to refresh a DataTable in the same form with different data. When I select an option I get a Javascript popup that says "malformedXML: During update: outerTab:j_idt185 not found" with no DataTable refresh and on inspecting the source I see an invisible iframe at the bottom of the page with id="JSFFrameId" that contains an element `<partial-response>` that in turn contains an element `<update id="outerTab:j_idt185" ...>` and this contains an element `<![CDATA[<div id="outerTab:j_idt185" class="ui-messages ui-widget" aria-live="polite"></div>]]>`. I think this references my `<messages>` tag, but nothing in the backing bean creates a message, and I do see an element in the page source `<div id="outerTab:facilitatorTestsForm:j_idt113" class="ui-messages ui-widget" aria-live="polite"></div>` where the messages should be, so the messages tag is indeed rendered. I can find no element with an ID containing "j_idt185" and apparently neither can some Javascript.

The "outerTab" in the IDs is a PrimeFaces TabView that contains all this stuff.

A page refresh causes the update to happen and the DataTable shows the correct data for the selected SelectOneMenu option.

I have found several posts by balusC where some element that is updated by an ajax call has a rendered value that makes it not render and therefore unable to be found when the update is called for. The target of my update (the DataTable) has no rendered attribute and is visible all the time, so this is a different problem. Other posts speak to a bug in earlier versions of PrimeFaces (I am using 6.1). I cannot figure out why this error occurs.

@Kukeltje kindly pointed me to several posts showing that using an encoding type of multipart/form-data in a file-upload component or a form submit can cause this problem but my page has neither of these.

Here is an excerpt of my page:

```
<div align="center">        
    <h:form id="facilitatorTestsForm">
        <p:messages for="testBeanMessages" showSummary="true" showDetail="true" globalOnly="true" escape="false" autoUpdate="true" />
        Tests for which event? 
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{testBean.selectedEventId}" style="top: 7px; ">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="All Tests" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.facilitatorEvents}" var="event" itemValue="#{event.id}" itemLabel="#{event.name}"  />
            <f:ajax update="facilitatorTests" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:commandButton value="Add a New Test" style="margin: 20px;" oncomplete="PF('newTestDialog').show();" actionListener="#{testBean.createEmptyNewTest}" immediate="true" />
        <p:dataTable var="test" value="#{testBean.testsForFacilitator}" rowIndexVar="index" id="facilitatorTests" widgetVar="facilitatorTests" selectionMode="single" selection="#{testBean.selectedTest}" rowKey="#{test.id}">
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="PF('facilitatorEditTestDialog').show(); " update="@form:facilitatorEditTestDialog" />
            <p:column>#{index + 1}</p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Test" sortBy="#{test.name}" width="40%"><h:outputText value="#{test.name}" /></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Tester" sortBy="#{test.tester.fullname}"><h:outputText value="#{test.tester.fullname}" /></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Manager" sortBy="#{test.manager.fullname}"><h:outputText value="#{test.manager.fullname}" /></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Event" sortBy="#{test.event.name}"><h:outputText value="#{test.event.name}" /></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Functional Area" sortBy="#{test.functionalArea.name}"><h:outputText value="#{test.functionalArea.name}" /></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Complete" width="150" sortBy="#{test.completionDate}"><h:outputText  value="#{test.completionDate == null ? 'Not Completed' : test.completionDate}"><f:convertDateTime pattern="M/d/yyyy hh:mm a" /></h:outputText></p:column>
            <p:column id="delete" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; min-width: 54px; ">
                <p:commandButton update="facilitatorTests" process="facilitatorTests" icon="ui-icon-close" actionListener="#{testBean.deleteTest(test.id)}"
                        title="If the test has not been completed, it will be deleted permanently. Otherwise it will be archived."/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
<... a few dialogs with conditional rendering ...>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

I have tried different targets for the selectOneMenu update attribute and it does not change the behavior so I believe it is correct.

Primefaces 6.1
Mojarra JSF API & IMPL 2.2.4
EL 3.0.0
Tomcat 7

Is this a JSF bug? Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: I hope you understand this is to little information. In [ask] they request an [mcve] not snippets. And as a good well educated developer you certainly know version info is relevant.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that - I may have erred on the side of "minimal" but I don't want to bury the problem in the noise of my bloated code. I thought that providing the widget that initiates the ajax call and the widget that gets updated was sufficient but this problem is so weird I don't know what else to provide. I don't think the backing bean code is relevant but I don't know. I suspect that if the problem as described doesn't trigger some recognition more code won't help. What version info do you think is relevant? I did provide my Primefaces version.

Comment: Jsf version (and impl). Agreed, posting 'bloated code' is not good but this is not very useful either... And remove all additional frameworks etc... more code is not a problem as long as it is an [mcve]. So minimal as well just to reproduce the problem on your side. Then it is very easy for someone else to try to reproduce. Or even debug...

Comment: This "good well educated developer" (thanks for the undeserved compliment) had no idea that JSF was not INCLUDED with Primefaces. Versions added to post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then you most likely know there are two 'implementations': Mojarra and MyFaces.

Comment: I do now. The groupid in my POM is com.sun.faces so I assume this is Mojarra. Added to post.

Comment: Try posting 'JSFFrameId iframe' in google... I got relevant hits. (encodingType related)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure (since I never ran into this myself and cannot try on my phone now) but I think you misunderstood the other posts. It's not the combination of the mentioned encodingType (which you do have) and fileupload but the fact in a form with this encodingType (needed for an upload) one also has normal form elements. This IS your case. Try removing the encodingType.

Comment: I totally missed that I had a form encodingType specified, thank you for pointing this out. There is no need for one - I have no fileupload anywhere in the app. It must have been an inadvertent copy/paste. I removed the encoding from all my forms (and my code in this post) and still have the problem. Since the offending element in the iframe has a ui-messages style I removed all the form validation and messages, too, no change. Strangely I have several very similar forms elsewhere in the app that do not have the problem and I cannot see any difference.

Comment: Make 100% sure the change is deployed. Make other textual changes that prove this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164436/discussion-between-snakedog-and-kukeltje).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Thanks to @Kukeltje for staying with me through this even if he did downvote my question for not having enough info :)

It comes back to @BalusC's posts about not rendering the target of an ajax update. In this case I had several PrimeFaces TabView tabs containing `<p:messages>` tags with `autoUpdate="true"`, and the tabs are shown/hidden depending on the role of the user. When I removed `autoUpdate="true"` from these messages tags the problem went away. Apparently every time I did an ajax post, even if I had partial submit limited to rendered subelements of the current visible tab, `autoUpdate` causes JSF to try to update the messages tags in the unrendered tabs and of course they cannot be found.

The way I found this was to put id attributes EVERYWHERE, on every element in my forms. Then the Javascript error pointed me to a named (id'd) element, rather than one with an automatically assigned ID that I could not trace, and when I saw "autoUpdate" the light bulb came on. Moral: put ids on EVERYTHING.

I hope this helps someone with the same symptom to look for autoUpdate everywhere.

And @Kukeltje you were right that my post had inadequate information - without the enclosing tab tags with their rendered attributes you could not have seen the problem. Since they were in another template that `ui:include`s the forms I did not think they were relevant. Wrongo!

Comment: And I removed the downvote because you were actively and positively responding to the comments. Thanks for that, it is an incentive to keep helping with this Q. Many other people do not. And now you see why an  [mcve] is most often requested, it actually serves a good purpose. And regarding the id's, that was going to be my next suggestion. For this also see NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler (using omnifaces is a good thing regardless